# A problem occurred while trying to set the "References" parameter for the IDE's in-process compiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I get the following error while trying to build a normal C# application.

> Error 1   A problem occurred while trying to set the "References" parameter for the IDE's in-process compiler. No metadata was found.

Comment: What were you doing when this happened? What have you tried to solve it? Can you reproduce it? Give us some more to go on.

Comment: A project that used to be running properly earlier. I reinstalled my windows, visual studio etc. After that I opened this solution file that contains 6 projects. The said projects has as references added to it the a class library produced as output of one of the said projects. It is compiled fine. However upon trying to build this particular project, it is an addon onto IE, it gives the said error. No idea how else to reproduce it.

Comment: I had the same problem. A VS2010 restart solved the problem for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved. Upon closer inspection found the error MSB3021. Accidentally an app.config file had been added to the .csproj file. But since no error was there this error was being thrown out. Removing that from solution explorer fixed it.